# Random Forest in Python: different prediction on all datas vs prediction on a single row

Tags: random-forest, predict

I have trained and tested a model with a standard code such as this one:

`rfc = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=200,bootstrap=False,max_features= 20, n_jobs=4)`

`rfc.fit(X_train,y_train)`

`predictions = rfc.predict(X_test)`

The results are pretty good as you can see in the confusion matrix
[image]

Then I tried to predict a single value of the dataset, using the model just trained, expecting to get the same result in terms of 0/1

```
single_row = [[57.0, '1', 3.0, 23321.33, 2325.74, 6200.0, 1307.0, 139.0, 1.0, 0.0,
       0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 61732.4, 0.0,
       23321.33, 0.0, 2.0, 7733.59, 0.0, 7448.0, 285.59, 0.0, 630.74, 1,
       1, 49.0, 71.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 45.0, 2724.42, 7122.33, 2.0, 35.0,
       2709.2, 15.22, 0.0, 11.0, 17.0]]
rfc.predict(single_row)

array([0.])
```

As you can see, I get as a prediction "0", while in the predictions obteined with the whole dataset, that specific row got (correctly) a prediction of 1. Actually, if I submit row by row to the predict command, I always get a prediction of 0 !

I saw that in R, there is the way to submit to the predict command the dataset of training as well, but I cannot find that option in the package on Python.

Is there something different from predicting the whole dataset, after having trained and tested the model, and predicting a single row ?

In a random Forest Model, do you have always to submit the whole dataset to get the predictions ?

thx
Dario

Comment: Ciao Dario, with the sklearn "RandomForestClassifier" it is clearly possible to make predictions on a single instance just as well as on a batch of instances. Are you sure that you see always zero when trying to predict a single sample? or the class zero ALMOST always win?  Maybe you already know it, but the fact that you're getting different results usually means that the format of the single input does not match the format used during training. Be sure to apply the same preprocessing steps to the single instance as you did during training and testing!

Comment: Hi Myron_Ben3, thx for your reply that pushed me to check again the model. Indeed, you are right. I tried again and the RandomForestClassifier can handle the single instance, giving the same result as the batch one. Thx again for having me confirmed this. Last time a tried several times, and actually I couldnt get the result I expected.

Comment: Ok, good for you! bye!